# Rails + Cucumber: How to test for link with certain text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link < a href = "http://www.yahoo.com">hello< / a >. How would I use cucumber to test that the link is there? `page.should have_selector` doesn't seem to have the option to specify what the text of the link is. I'm looking for the assertion version of `click_link('hello')`. I can also search by href value as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
page.should have_link('hello')
```

See https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/spec/session/has_link_spec.rb for some examples